# Let $S=\{(a,b,c)\in [100]:a<b \,, a<c\}$ find $|S|$

Tags: probability

Let $S=\{(a,b,c)\in [100]:a<b \,, a<c\}$ find $|S|$

I'm newbie in probability and i try to make this exercise.

**My work:**

We know for example $(1,2,3)\in S$, and $(17,23,20)\in S$.

Moreover, we know the number of subset of $[100]$ of cardinality $3$ is:

${100}\choose{2}$ =$\frac{100!}{2!(98)!}=\frac{99\times100}{2}=50\times99=4950$

Then exists $4950$ subsets of $[100]$ of cardinality 3 
however, not all of these sets satsify $a<b$ and $a<c$ can someone help me to solve this?

Comment: What is [100] ? I suppose it is $[0,100]\cap\mathbb N$, do you consider the zero ?

Comment: $[n]=\{1,2,...,n\}$ then $[100]=\{1,2,...,100\}$ @zwim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$${~~~~~~S=\{(a,b,c)\in[100]^3: a<b, a<c\}\\ [100]=\{1,..,100\}}$$

For every value of $a$ there are $(100-a)^2$ ways to select $b,c$ (with replacement).   Now $a$ may take any value from $1$ to $99$.

$$\begin{align}\lvert S\rvert &= \sum_{a=1}^{99} (100-a)^2 \\&= \sum_{z=1}^{99}z^2\\ &= \phantom{990000-\frac{200\cdot 99\cdot 100}{2}+\frac{99\cdot100\cdot 199}{6}}\end{align}$$

Comment: Excellenttttttt!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you are asking.

- $(a,b,c)$ is a triplet, there are $100^3$ such triplets.
- $\{a,b,c\}$ is a subset there are ${100\choose 3}$ such subsets.
- But if you consider triplets $(a,b,c)$ such that $\{a,b,c\}$ is a subset of $\{1,\cdots,100\}$ there are $3!$ times more of them because triplets are ordered.

This is why I gave you two answers below, if this is not the interpretation you intended, please edit your question.

---

Let $S=\{(a,b,c)\in\{1,2,\cdots,100\}^3\mid a<b,a<c\}$

Whenever $a$ is fixed you have $a<b,c\le 100\quad$ so $\quad(100-a)$ choices for $b$ and also for $c$.

So $|S|=\sum\limits_{a=1}^{100}(100-a)^2=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{99} k^2=\dfrac{99.100.199}{6}=328350$

---

Let $S=\{(a,b,c):\{a,b,c\}\subset\{1,2,\cdots,100\}\text{ and }a<b,a<c\}$

Whenever $a$ is fixed you have $a<b,c\le 100$ and $b\neq c\quad$ so $\quad(100-a)$ choices for $b$ and $(99-a)$ for $c$.

So $|S|=\sum\limits_{a=1}^{100}(100-a)(99-a)=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{98} k(k+1)=\dfrac{98.99.197}{6}+\dfrac{98.99}{2}=323400$

Answer (score 0):

There are ${100 \choose 3} = \frac{100!}{6!97!} = 161700$ ways to pick three numbers from the set $\{1, \ldots, 100\}$, such that all three are unequal.

Take one of those sets of three numbers, choose the smallest value as $a$ (since it must be smaller than both the other numbers). Then you have two options left for $b$, and that leaves one choice for $c$. So for any set $\{x, y, z | x < y < z\}$, there are two possible triples: $(x, y, z)$ or $(x, z, y)$. Since this is true for any $\{x, y, z\}$ out of the $161700$ possible options, the total number of triples is $161700 \times 2 = 323400$.